# Динамическое создание кнопки с использованием xml в android приложении

Tags: android, xml, вёрстка

Есть задача: необходимо динамически создать кнопку. Описание кнопки находится в xml файле:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="80sp"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ring_button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />
```

Как видно, background ссылается на еще один xml файл (ring_button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE"/>
    <stroke android:width="12sp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

Как динамически создать кнопку, описанную в этих файлах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете файл`layout_your_button.xml` в папке `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ring_button"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Дальше в коде, где надо создать кнопку динамически:

```
Button button = (Button) LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout_your_button, null);
```

Вообще, точно так же, как и элемент списка создавать (`ListView`). Работали со списками с кастомным элементом?

Comment: Можно поподробнее, что происходит в коде?

Comment: Желательно и сразу родительский контейнер указывать, иначе потом придется все `layout_*` снова задавать при добавлении в контейнер.

Comment: @DeathCookies, При помощи `LayoutInflator` создается из `xml` `View`, в вашем случае это кнопка.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть `LayoutInflater`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_LAYOUT_FILE, null);
```

или

```
View view = LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_LAYOUT_FILE, null);
```

Comment: у Context нет метода getLayoutInflater()

Comment: @metalurgus, да, поспешил с ответом. исправил.